# Guice: inject the ContainerRequestContext into an interceptor

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I have a Dropwizard app, I would like to be able to inject the `ContainerRequestContext` for the given request into an interceptor, basically something like this:

```java
# Guice configuration to set up the interceptor.  
Provider<ContainerRequestContext> ctxProvider = getProvider(ContainerRequestContext.class);
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any(), new SecurityInterceptor(ctxProvider));
```

And my intercepter will look like:

```java
public class SecurityInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    private final Provider<ContainerRequestContext> ctxProvider;

    public SecurityInterceptor(Provider<ContainerRequestContext> ctxProvider) {

        this.ctxProvider = ctxProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext = ctxProvider.get();
        // Logic with using ctx
        return methodInvocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

However when I try the above I get the following error upon starting

```
1) No implementation for javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext was bound.
```

How do I configure Guice so that I can inject a `ContainerRequestContext` provider?

Comment: It looks like you need to provide a binding for ContainerRequestContext

Comment: Why don't you just use the HK2 AOP support? It works seamlessly with Jersey. You will have no problem `@Inject`ing the request context. Check [this](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-validate-return) out.